# System.Drawing.dll not found

Tags: unity, c#

I am creating an asset, in Unity, and I need to use `System.Drawing`. I have been trying to figure out how to add the DLL in a way that works, but I have had zero luck. I have tried adding the DLL to the assets folder, but it just shows up in Visual Studio as if it couldn't be found. I have also followed the instructions of [a similar question, on the Unity Answers page](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/53170/using-drawing-package-like-systemdrawing.html), without any luck.

How do I use `System.Drawing` in Unity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450251/how-to-reference-system-drawing-in-visual-studio-2010-express

Comment: Are you getting an error or exception message? If so, including it may help.

Comment: @Pikalek If I add the dll into the assets folder like I see all over the internet then I get an exclamation on the entry in the references for System.Drawing like it doesn't exist.

Comment: When you say you add it to the assets folder.. are you just dragging it into assets, and still trying to reference it as `System.Drawing`? *generally*, it doesn't work that way. I've only had such links work if I also created the *folder* hierarchy.

Comment: Reversing my vote. I figured it out, and fair enough, there was a slight caveat to the other conditions that *eventually* made this very easy, but *at first* made this a pain in the rear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around with `System.Drawing` from my Windows folder, and noting that *all* answers on Google appeared to be incorrect in some way or another, I re-read the first answer I came across. I believe others have mentioned it, and at least one of the other answers attempts to utilise it. I will provide it, here, with all of the included steps. I was able to solve this problem after only *carefully* reading step one.

---

> **Best Answer** 
> **Answer** by [DarkCloud14](http://answers.unity3d.com/users/26600/darkcloud14.html) · May 16, 2012 at 10:55 PM 
> Hi there,
> not sure if still someone wants to know how to use System.Drawing even if it's not officially supported by Unity. Ok here is what I've found out for Unity 3.5.1f2 so far:
>
> 1. If you wanna use it and don't want to get Errors in Unity Editor (not MonoDevelop) you must drag the file System.Drawing.dll into your Project tree. On default Windows Installation the file can be found in the following directory: `%Unity Folder%\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0` on OSX it should be in the Unity.app in somewhere. You may also be able to use the current `System.Drawing.dll` of Mono 2.10.8 but I didn't test this yet.
> 2. The Api Compatibility Level must be set to .NET 2.0!! The option ".NET 2.0 Subset" doesn't work.
> 3. For a Windows only version you would be done now and it should work. I didn't test the whole functionality of System.Drawing!! I just tested some of the Bitmap functionality.
> 4. Additional step for MacOSX: After you've build the Application you should open the .app/Contents directory. Create a Plugins directory there and the copy the file libgdiplus.dylib from the lib directory of Mono 2.10.8 for OSX (On windows you can use 7-zip and some other tools to get the libgdiplus.dylib from the OSX download image)! After another test the version of Unity at least the one shipped with Windows Unity doesn't work. Now rename the file libgdiplus.dylib to gdiplus.dll.bundle. After that it should also work under OSX.

---

You will note the inclusion of accessing `%UnityFolder%\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0`, much like the alternate answer. You should note that **this is not** where you put `System.Drawing.dll`. In fact, if you have done so in following the previous answer, read on; you may have caused some damage.

This is actually where you will *find* `System.Drawing.dll`; or at least, the version you want to copy and paste to your *Assets* folder. The version from your *Windows* folder is likely of a newer version, as was the case, with me. You might prefer the newer version, but unfortunately, Unity does not. They are simply not compatible.

The version you find in your *mono* folder *is* compatible. It is for this reason that I advise against attempting to *place* `System.Drawing.dll` here. You will likely overwrite the older version with the newer version, which is not compatible with Unity.

---

To sum up, access `%UnityFolder%\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0` to locate a *compatible* version of `System.Drawing.dll`. Copy this file to your assets folder. You should immediately note the inclusion of `System.Drawing.dll` in your script references<sup>1</sup>, and be able to use it as intended.

<sub><sup>1</sup> At least, it is immediately noticeable in MonoDevelop.</sub>

Comment: In case relevant in context (in this context, I do not think it is, so have not included it in my actual answer), the incompatibility appears to be caused by .NET versions. The editor will still view the `System.Drawing.dll` found in the *Windows* folder, if dragged in, but will request disabling "runs in editor" due to .NET compatibility issues. Another answer suggests opening the entire `System.Drawing` file, in Visual Studio, and manually changing the .NET version. As it stands, current version is 4.0. As far as I am aware, Unity only supports up to 3.5.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did indeed copy System.Drawing into that directory so I must have lost the 3.5 version as mine is 4.0. Any idea where I can get a 3.5 version easily?

Comment: Is that the correct link? It says the ID is incorrect.

Comment: @saboehnke, weird, I copied the link and had the same issue. [Here is an alternate](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=34426970621718472249)

Comment: you are a life saver. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: This did not work for me on OSX, but the answer is pretty old. I offer no other solution, just letting anyone else know who stumbles on this.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS 10.12 with Unity 5.6.1f1, System.Drawing.dll was in `/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Mono/lib/mono/2.0`.

Comment: The best thing to do when you lack rep is to first build up rep by posting your own questions and answers. Using an answer to try to work around the commenting restriction is generally frowned upon and leads to the post being downvoted or deleted. I think in this case this post contains enough information to count as a legitimate, if sparse answer, so you can start earning rep now if you'd like to edit and elaborate on how to use this information.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, DMGregory. I wouldn't consider my response to be a full answer, since the question doesn't ask *where* to find System.Drawing.dll. Really, it's just an augmentation of Gnemlock's thorough answer. It's valuable information that would have saved me a meaningful amount of time, so I'll leave it here for others to decide whether it can stay as an answer. The best option (from an etiquette-naive perspective) seems to be for someone else to add it as a comment under their name, and then I or whomever can delete this answer.